# how to calculate the order of elliptic curves?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

when E is an elliptic curve,
$E:F(x,y)=y^2+a_1x y+a_3y-x^3-a_2x^2-a_4x-a_6=0$

and O=[0,1,0] is the base point,
then
$ord_O(x)=-2,ord_O(y)=-3$.

why is it?
please teach me how to calculate the order.

it is written on p48.proposition1.5 of the book(GTM106,the arithmetic of elliptic curves).

Answer (score 1):

This is the order of a function at a point on an elliptic curve.
We really should use projective coordinates, so
the equation is $F(X,Y,Z)=Y^2Z+a_1XYZ+\cdots=0$. Then $x=X/Z$ is a
rational function
on the projective plane with divisor $(L_1)-(L_2)$ where $L_1$ is the
line $X=0$ and $L_2$ is the line $Z=0$. If $P$ is a point on $E$ then
$\textrm{ord}_P(x)=i_P(E,L_1)-i_P(E,L_2)$ where $i_P(E,L)$
is the intersection multiplicity of $E$ and $L$ at the point $P$.
Here $i_O(E,L_2)=3$ as the point $O$ is an inflection point, and $L_2$
(the line at infinity) is the tangent to $E$ at $O$. Also $L_1$
passes through $O$ but is not a tangent, so $i_p(E,L_1)=1$.

The calculation for $\textrm{ord}_O(y)$ is similar, but a little bit easier.

Comment: Thanks. In your comment,If  P
  is a point on E
 then $ord_P(x)=i_P(E,L_1)−i_P(E,L_2)$,why is it? The definition of order in the book was different. $ord_p(f)=${$d∈Z:f∈M_p^d$}

Comment: I understand that $ord_p(x)= ord_p(X/Z)= ord_p(X)- ord_p(Z)$,but don't that $ord_p(X)=i_p(E,L_1)$ nor $ord_p(Z)=i_p(E,L_2)$.